# Data is not being Ordered in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting this `sqlScripts=error CS0103: The name 'sqlScripts' does not exist in the current context`

```
 var sqlScripts = tc.Input.SqlScript;       
 sqlScripts = sqlScripts.OrderBy(x => x.Priority).ToList();
```

Where I read the data from JSON file:

```
"SqlScript": [
  {
    "ScriptName": "/StaticScripts/Test_002.sql",
    "Priority": 1
  },
  {
    "ScriptName": "/SqlScripts/Test_002.sql",
    "Priority": 2
  }
],
```

The data is ok in the SqlScript, though it does not order the list, I can't see why.

```
public class ScriptPriority
{
    public string ScriptName { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

and Setting the data as:  `public List<ScriptPriority> SqlScript { get; set; }` which gets the values from JSON. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are ordering strings and not number.  So the string order is 1,10,100,2,20,200,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: Not following, shouldn't it be ordering the data by Priority? What should then I change, not seeing.

Comment: sorry your post confuses me. "I am getting this sqlScripts=error CS0103:" where do you get this error? "The data is ok in the SqlScript, though it does not order the list, I can't see why." how is the data ok? what does that mean? what is the actual ordering result?

Comment: Sorry, the data In the sqlScripts is stored as a list e.g. sqlScripts[0] shows an object etc... Yes You are correct I am getting this error as well now, It looks like executing the second time gives another error, though I am lost in this.

Comment: @Mong Zhu, are you able to get rid of this error? If so how?

Comment: Your question is confusing as hell. I'm sorry but I can't understand any of it.

Comment: Please clearly describe your steps (reading from json, ordering), then tell us exactly in which step your error occures. As the error mentions `sqlScripts`(watch the case), I dont think the error actually occurs in the code you show.

Comment: First of all, don't use `var` in StackOverflow questions. I have no idea what type `sqlScripts` is. Secondly, the error you are quoting is a compile-time error. That's got nothing to do with ordering.

Comment: You need to parse string numbers to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the JSON the Model will look like below. I have used https://json2csharp.com/

```
public class Root
{
    public List<SqlScript> SqlScript { get; set; }
}
public class SqlScript
{
    public string ScriptName { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

After `Deserialize`, I was able to order by `Priority`

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(jsonfile);
var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

var result = output.SqlScript.OrderBy(x => x.Priority);
```